# CSS Issues with text

Tags: css, text

OK, I'm doing an eBook for my AS level,
I've inserted some text but there is an issue, I was wondering if anybody knew how to fix this.
I am using notebook++ for all the coding.

CSS:

```
p {
    font-family: Arial, Halvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

TEXT:

```
-can't
-"friends list"
```

instead when I load up the website these words look like this:

```
-canâ€™t
-â€~friend listâ€™
```

Comment: Check encoding of your PHP/HTML code/string. It must be UTF-8 Without BOM for best capability.

Comment: note: Helvetica is misspelled.

Comment: @georgey290 in Notepad++ You can set the encoding, the dropdown is between 'view' & 'Language'. Just make sure that Notepad++ is not imposing an incorrect encoding type on your file. Set it as suggested as above

Comment: @Justinas, PHP was not mentioned in the question; on the contrary, this is about an eBook. And UTF-8 *with* BOM is definitely safer for HTML. PHP has issues with the BOM, but that’s an entirely different story.

Answer (score 0):

You have saved the file as UTF-8 without BOM in Notepad++. Open the file and save it as just “UTF-8”, which means UTF-8 with [BOM](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark) (Byte Order Mark). In addition, add the following tag at the start of the `head` part:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

(using this XHTML syntax, since e-book formats are based on XHTML).

Unfortunately, this may not suffice. Some versions of IE give preference to HTTP headers over BOM, contrary to what the HTML5 spec says. This means that you should inspect the headers e.g. using Rex Swain’s [HTTP Viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html). If the `Content-Type` header contains a `charset` parameter value other than `utf-8`, you need to have a) that value changed to `utf-8`, in a manner that depends on the server software and administration, or b) failing that, change your page to use the encoding declared in the header; in Notepad++, you can use the Convert command to convert to ANSI (which here means windows-1252) – but if there are characters outside the windows-1252 repertoire, you need to change them to character references *before* such a conversion.

You actually have “smart” quotes in your content:
can’t
“friends list”
This is just fine. But when the UTF-8 encoded “smart” quotes are misinterpreted as windows-1252 encoded, the result is just what the question shows. This may happen due to a `meta` tag or an HTTP header that declares windows-1252 or due to browser defaults for documents that do not declared their character encoding.

Note: CSS is not involved here in any way. The issue is just the character encoding of the HTML encoding. CSS will have an effect on the *visual appearance* (style) of the “smart quotes”, when browsers start actually rendering them after the fix.